# Верно ли тут тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Допущена ли женщина к причастию и отпущены ли ей грехи – не сообщается.

Answer (score 4):

> *Допущена ли женщина к причастию и отпущены ли ей грехи – не сообщается.*
>
> **Верно ли** тут тире?

.

Такая пунктуация **правильна.**

См. [**ПАС**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/#id-11%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8):

> **§124.** В сложноподчиненном предложении может ставиться **тире**:
>
> 1) после придаточной части, стоящей перед главной частью...
>
> *Когда тоска – хорошо писать.*

Answer (score 2):

**Здесь без тире никак не обойтись.**

1) Тире ставится даже в нераспространенных предложениях при инверсии придаточного **изъяснительного** предложения:  Он приедет, но когда – не знаю. Хорошо, что они венчаются, а как жить будут – кто знает. Как рассказывал учитель – долго слушал у окна я.

2) В нашем случае мы имеем **однородные** придаточные изъяснительные, связанные союзом И, и **разную структуру** двух частей предложения, **поэтому пауза обязательна.**

3) Примеры:

Кстати, кому конкретно принадлежат роскошные виллы  ― **не сообщается.**

Кто виноват из них, кто прав, – судить не нам. При бессоюзной связи придаточных может использоваться **запятая и тире как единый знак.**